# Datatable merge on non primary key column

Tags: c#, sql, firebird

I am using `dataTable1.merge(dataTable2)` to merge 2 tables/

First table is table from one database and has columns `ROBAID, NAZIV`

Second table is table from second database and has columns `ROBAID, STANJE, KOLICINA`

Function above worked with this code:

```
dt1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt1.Columns["ROBAID"] };
dt2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt2.Columns["ROBAID"] };

dt1.Merge(dt2);
```

And it was ok since in `dt1` it is really primary key but in `dt2` primary key is `ID`, but I was using it like this because I was not planning to have 2 same `ROBAID` in it. Problem now is that plans changed and I HAVE 2 same `ROBAID` in `dt2`, but still I need to merge them. How can I accomplish that?

Example of table 1:

```
| ROBAID | NAZIV |
| 1      | R1    |
| 2      | R2    |
| 3      | R3    |
| 4      | R4    |
```

Example of table 2:

```
| ID  | ROBAID | KOLICINA | STANJE |
| 1   | 2      |    2     |  2     |
| 2   | 2      |    4     |  2     |
| 3   | 3      |    1     |   1    |
| 4   | 2      |    3     |   2    |
```

As you can see, in table 2 column `ROBAID` doesn't have unique values anymore.

Comment: what end result do you want to get with this data ?

Comment: I want to get `table2` + column `NAZIV` from table 1 like i used `LEFT JOIN` but these are 2 tables from 2 different databases

Comment: Are both databases Firebird ? http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq16/

Comment: They both are firebird

Comment: Then perhaps you can do that `left join` with some sql scaffolding

Comment: How could I do it with 2 databases?

Comment: by making requests on `external source`, link is above. Also see Firebird 2.5 SQL reference on the official site.